# Ajax with MVC in java design issue?

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications

I am having problems in designing simple MVC (from scratch) with AJAX. I am using Servlets, HTML and JQuery.

According to the architecture and standards we should use request.forward() to transfer to another page after processing to show the output/error, also we should not use System.out.println() in Servlets.

**My Problems:**

1. I have to use AJAX so I can't change the page, meaning request.forward() cant be used.
2. I have to use System.out.println() in the Servlet to transfer data from the Servlet to AJAX call, then parsing it.

**Question:**

1. How do I get data from the Servlet to Javascript in my approach?
2. I am not following MVC because the Servlet is not using request.forward(). How do I use it in my case?

**Note :**

I know other approaches of JSP and Struts etc. but can you kindly help me with my approach?

Comment: I believe you can use request.forward() to a JSP and the entire JSP content (compiled and run to produce HTML) will be returned to your web page in your Ajax Response.  I use it regularly and it works like a charm.  Correct me if I am misinterpreting your question.  
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for response ,
I am using json for data transfer and I think using this way , my problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to send data (as JSON or XML, for example) from the servlet to the JavaScript, then you don't need any JSP. The view, in this case, is handled completely at client-side. The usual way is to use a Java bean to store the data to send, marshal this bean to JSON or XML, and send the JSON or XML to the response writer.

If the goal is to send HTML to the JavaScript (to send a portion of the page to refresh, for example), then you can forward the request to a JSP that will generate this HTML portion only, and not a whole new page.

In the end, it's up to the AJAX callback function to get the data or HTML from the response and update the HTML page.

Comment: Here I am having confusion with the first approach. If you say to use response writer that means to generate directly the output at servlet (means to use out.prinltn() ) but according to my understanding it is not as per MVC and also it creates chances to through exception to the view. Correct me if I am wrong.